# Network in Simulator IOS

Tags: ios, networking, proxy, ios-simulator

I'm a newbie of IOS. I have a problem with network of IOS Simulator. I'll explain more detail as below.

I have a URL ***abc.com/infor.json***  that I want to read the information of my app before display main screen.
I also have to network : Network A, Network B
As far as I know, Simulator is using same network with MACbook.

1. MAC connect to network A:

   - Safari of MAC and Safari of Simulator can open this URL
   - Application CAN read the information from URL -> App works fine !
2. MAC connect to network B:

   - Safari of MAC and Safari of Simulator can open this URL
   - Application CAN read the information from URL -> App **DOES NOT** work!

I really don't know what is the exactly reason in this problem
- Of course , it's not app's problem -> Because my app works fine with network A
- If network B has proxy'problem -> Why URL can be open by Simulator's Safari

Please help me to resolve it.
Thank you so much

Comment: Are you trying to run a Cisco simulator in Safari? I don't understand.

Comment: I think you should update your question, it is not clearly and conflict between this two lines:
    -Safari of MAC and Safari of Simulator can open this URL
    -Safari of MAC and Safari of Simulator CAN NOT open this URL -> App DOES NOT work!

Comment: Sorry ! I already edited

Comment: I still don't see what this has to do with IOS, which only runs on Cisco devices, unless you are using a network simulator.